# I prefer getting up early (rather) than rushing at the last minute

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions, comparative

As written in the title:

> I prefer getting up early **rather** than rushing at the last minute.

Why do I have to include ''**rather**" when it already makes sense if you omit the 'rather' word. So it goes specifically like this:

> I prefer getting up early than rushing at the last minute.

Right? Doesn't add up really... kindly elucidate this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's wrong to omit "rather" because it won't sound right. (It doesn't sound right to me as a native speaker.) This is because "than" is not preceded by a comparative (or followed by one, if the order is inverted). There needs to be a comparative, such as:

> Getting up early is **better** than rushing at the last minute.

Compare these definitions for [than](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/than) and [rather than](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/rather?q=rather%2Bthan), for example.

---

---

Here's a little history, as a bonus:

A very long time ago, it would have been OK to omit "rather", such as in:

> The Apprentices being encouraged herewith [...], than to do nothing, brake open some Prisons.
>   <sub>[The life and raigne of King Henry VIII](https://books.google.com/books?id=aYPgaMA-mf4C&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22do+nothing,+brake+open+some+prisons%22.), 1649</sub>

It looks like this construct was last used sometime in the 1600s (and at that point, as you can see, spelling and capitalization were a little different than they are now). The passage itself does sound very weird to me.

Comment: Agreed. You could, for fun, split the better/than & make it appear at a quick glance to only be relying on the 'than'. "Better to get up early than rush at the last minute."